# Swift Array elements to variables

Tags: swift, vapor

I am making a web application in Vapor.

I have an array of things, e.g :

> ["thing", "other thing", "third thing"]

I want to make empty string variables with the same names but `" "` replaced with `"+"` in a struct.

I cannot use a dictionary or an array as vapor wants individual variables in strings. The reason I cannot write them all manually is that I want to be able to add things to my array and not have to also add them somewhere else.

I can do the replacing by myself, I just need to know if it is possible to make variables out of the array elements.

I am new to Swift, I do not know where to start.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you mean with making variable out of array elements? you want variables named `thing`, `other+thing,...` of type string? Maybe it would be better to explain why (what problem are you trying to solve) because this is a strange request.

Comment: I want to read POST request data with vapor, but in order to do that, I need variables with all possible keys in the URL. I have an array of those possible keys, but vapor needs String variables in a struct.

Comment: So you need a class or struct that corresponds to the parameters in the POST request?

Comment: Yes. All the parameter names possible are in an array.

Comment: I don't see why you don't create such class yourself then, you must know what data to expect.

Comment: The reason I don't want to create it myself is because this array will have things added, removed, and changed and can possibly reach hundreds of elements. Having all that in two places is very hard, but, if what I want is impossible, I will have to do that.

Comment: Do you really have one post request that can have 100+ elements or is that the union of all your post requests? Normally you have a model class with some properties and each property is one element in the request. Maybe you just need to structure your data?

Answer (score 2):

```swift
let array = ["thing", "other thing", "third thing"]
let newArray = array.map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+") }

print(newArray)
// ["thing", "other+thing", "third+thing"]
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is relevant to what's being asked (which isn't that clear I must admit).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. You could use `@dynamicMemberLookup` to dynamically look for struct/class property. Here is an example but I don't know exactly where is your purpose to use this and if this would help you.

```
import Foundation

let replaced = ["thing", "other thing", "third thing"].map {$0.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")}

@dynamicMemberLookup
struct User {
    subscript(dynamicMember m: String) -> String? {
        if replaced.contains(m) {
            return "soemthing for that thing"
        }

        return nil
    }
}

let u = User()
print(u.other_thing)
print(u.thinga)
```

Because + is not allowed in property names you must use _ insetad. If you realy want to access it with + you could do it with `print(u[dynamicMember: "other+thing"])`. To use this you must also replace `$0.replacingOccurrences` to replace `" "` with `+`.

Here is some more info about `@dynamicMemberLookup` https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html